# Error-Table doesn't have a primary key

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, .net, datatable

I know there a lot of other threads which are similar but they weren't helpful.So i get a couple of error messages on the same line below-

```
ds.Tables["Customers"].PrimaryKey = new DataColoumn[]{ds.Tables["Customers"].Coloumns["ID"]};
```

the error messages are

1. "the type or namespace name 'DataColoumn' could not be found(are you missing n using directive or assembly reference"
2. "system.data.datatable does not contain a definition of Columns and not extension method 'Columns' accepting a argument"

the entire method is below-

```
 private void GetDataFromDB()
 {
    string CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AK"].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS);
    string sqlQuery = "SELECT * from tblScheduledCalls";
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlQuery, con);

    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds,"Customers");

    ds.Tables["Customers"].PrimaryKey = new DataColoumn[]{ds.Tables["Customers"].Coloumns["ID"]};

    Cache.Insert("DATASET", ds, null, DateTime.Now.AddHours(24), System.Web.Caching.Cache.NoSlidingExpiration);

    gvCustomers.DataSource = ds;
    gvCustomers.DataBind();

    lblMessage.Text = "Data Loaded from Database";
    }
```

in the above code,i have already declared CustomerId as identity primary key in sql mgt studio.

---

Well such a silly mistake.but now there is another error which popped up while execution

"Table doesn't have a primary key" 
in the code below

```
protected void gvCustomers_RowUpdating1(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
  {
    if (Cache["DATASET"] != null)
    {
        DataSet ds = (DataSet)Cache["DATASET"];
        DataRow dr = ds.Tables["Customers"].Rows.Find(e.Keys["ID"]);
        dr["Names"] = e.NewValues["Names"];
        dr["ContactNo"] = e.NewValues["ContactNo"];
        dr["Email"] = e.NewValues["Email"];
        dr["City"] = e.NewValues["City"];
        dr["State"] = e.NewValues["State"];

        Cache.Insert("DATASET", ds, null, DateTime.Now.AddHours(24), System.Web.Caching.Cache.NoSlidingExpiration);
        gvCustomers.EditIndex = -1;
        GetDataFromCache();
    }
    }
```

Error on the line below-
      DataRow dr = ds.Tables["Customers"].Rows.Find(e.Keys["ID"]);

where i have already made CustomerId as identity primary key in sql mgt studio and also in the GetDataFromDB() method as above.why that?

Comment: DataColumn instead of DataColoumn

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: This is a simple typing error.

Comment: If VS were developed by Google, you would probably see "Did you mean DataColumn?"

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".